# Dependency of buoyancy on volume and mass of submerged object

Tags: buoyancy

When we fully submerge a volume of 1 litre, whether that mass is 1 kg or 100 kg, isn't the volume of the displaced liquid always the same and equal to the actual 1 litre, i.e. to the volume of the fully submerged object?

So in other words the buoyant force acting on a fully submerged object is only dependent to the volume of the object?

Of course for different fluids, the density of the fluid will play a role, but we are talking about the same fluid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 
Buoyancy force is dependent on:

- density of fluid
- gravitational acceleration
- submerged volume of a body

It does not matter if you are putting 2.7 kg block of aluminium or 7.4 kg block of tin. The buoyant force is the same.

Comment: You might want to reference Archimedes' Law, and maybe even the interesting (apocryphal?) [story of the goldsmith that tried to cheat the king when making a crown...](https://www.math.nyu.edu/~crorres/Archimedes/Crown/CrownIntro.html)

Comment: In particular, this is why only some things float: if the  is greater than the weight then they float, if not, they sink.

Answer (score 0):

Archimedes' principle of buoyant forces states that:

$$ {\vec F_B} = -\rho V \hspace{1pt}{\vec g}, $$

where $\rho$ = Density of the fluid, $V$ = Volume of body submerged in liquid, ${\vec g}$ = Acceleration due to gravity.

The physical interpretation is essentially that the water exerts a force opposite to the gravitational pull on the submerged part of the body.

Here's a nice image you can analyse with a force diagram to figure out the "effective weight" of a body when submerged as an exercise:

[image: exercise]